# Spring reactive connection prematurely closed BEFORE response reactor netty WebClient HttpClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, reactor-netty

WebClient configuration (minimized reproducible use case, tested with different durations, no effect):

```
    public WebClient createWebClient() {
        ConnectionProvider provider = ConnectionProvider.builder("WebClientProvider")
                .maxConnections(2)
                .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .maxLifeTime(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
                .pendingAcquireTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .evictInBackground(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .build();

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(provider).option(ChannelOption.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, 5000);

        ReactorClientHttpConnector reactorClientHttpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

        return WebClient.builder()
            .clientConnector(reactorClientHttpConnector)
            .build();
    }
```

Usage of the client, as a GET to a public cloud service provider:

```
    public Flux<SomeClass> doGetSomething() {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri(buildUri())
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(byte[].class)
                .flatMapMany(byteArray -> Flux.fromArray(byteArrayToModel(byteArray, SomeClass[].class)))
                .onErrorResume(e -> {
                    return Flux.error(new RuntimeException("Failed to call get", e));
                });
    }
```

Exception:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response; nested exception is reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException: Connection prematurely closed BEFORE response
    at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoLift] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Mono.error(Mono.java:330)
    org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.wrapException(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    *__________Mono.error ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.wrapException(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
    *__Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:106)
    |_           Mono.map ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:107)
    *________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFilterFunction.lambda$ofResponseProcessor$4(ExchangeFilterFunction.java:96)
    *________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFilterFunction.lambda$ofRequestProcessor$3(ExchangeFilterFunction.java:85)
    |_         checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET https://***********************.com/someendpoint*********************** [DefaultWebClient]
    |_ Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$7(DefaultWebClient.java:433)
    *__________Mono.defer ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebClient.java:430)
    |_       Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.bodyToMono(DefaultWebClient.java:540)
    |_   Mono.flatMapMany ⇢ at com.mycode(SomeClass.java:57)
Original Stack Trace:
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:141)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.lambda$onError$4(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.withActiveSpan(TracedSubscriber.java:95)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.onError(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:234)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.lambda$onError$4(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.withActiveSpan(TracedSubscriber.java:95)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.onError(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:234)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.lambda$onError$4(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.withActiveSpan(TracedSubscriber.java:95)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.onError(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:234)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.lambda$onError$4(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.withActiveSpan(TracedSubscriber.java:95)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.onError(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.lambda$onError$4(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.withActiveSpan(TracedSubscriber.java:95)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.onError(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.lambda$onError$4(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.withActiveSpan(TracedSubscriber.java:95)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.onError(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:225)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:274)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.lambda$onError$4(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.withActiveSpan(TracedSubscriber.java:95)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.onError(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.innerError(FluxConcatMap.java:309)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapInner.onError(FluxConcatMap.java:875)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4400)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:451)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:251)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:491)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.tryEmitNext(EmitterProcessor.java:299)
        at reactor.core.publisher.SinkManySerialized.tryEmitNext(SinkManySerialized.java:100)
        at reactor.core.publisher.InternalManySink.emitNext(InternalManySink.java:27)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:190)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.lambda$onError$4(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.withActiveSpan(TracedSubscriber.java:95)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.reactor.TracedSubscriber.onError(TracedSubscriber.java:79)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:194)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$HttpObserver.onUncaughtException(HttpClientConnect.java:384)
        at reactor.netty.ReactorNetty$CompositeConnectionObserver.onUncaughtException(ReactorNetty.java:670)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$DisposableAcquire.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:202)
        at reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider$PooledConnection.onUncaughtException(DefaultPooledConnectionProvider.java:450)
        at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundClose(HttpClientOperations.java:294)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelInactive(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:73)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:418)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:392)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec$Decoder.channelInactive(HttpClientCodec.java:326)
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelInactive(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:221)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:392)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.channelInactive(SslHandler.java:1074)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:813)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Test mechanism:
GET requests through insomnia to the reactive web app (clicking with the mouse on Send button continuously until it fails), requests failing intermittently, at random intervals with no obvious (for me), causes.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Versions:

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.6.6
io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.0.17
io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.0.17
io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.4.16
io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.75
org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.3.18
```

P.S.
Debugged internal libraries workflow, and got here, in reactor netty http:
[image]

Comment: I would suggest to update your versions. Also follow the recommendations here https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#faq.connection-closed

Comment: The cloud service provider(CP) sends the message, the order is: CP: [FIN, ACK], WebClient(WC): [ACK] [FIN, ACK], CP: [RST]. Problem is, this is happening randomly after an existing request, which was returned to the pool, is retrieved and a new request is attempted.

Comment: @VioletaGeorgieva if RestTemplate is used, with pooled configuration, no drops and errors are observed.

Comment: Try to debug what was the previous request. You may want to create an issue with a reproducible example.